# How to make history.back() without getting a warning on the browser to reload the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a "Back" button, so for that I used:

```
history.back();
```

It works fine when I run it locally, but when I deploy it to the server when I click on the button I get a message on the browser:

> Confirm Form Resubmission
>   This webpage requires data that you entered earlier in order to be properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you will repeat any action this page previously performed.
>
> Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.
>   ERR_CACHE_MISS

There is no problem resubmitting the form. I just want to avoid this message for the user. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: This isn't possible. The warning is because the previous page was loaded through a POST request, so the same submission needs to be made again, hence user permission must be given for security reasons.

Comment: Why it works when I run it locally? So I'll need to pass the parameters to the next screen, and on the back button I'll need to submit a new request to the screen I had before, to mock the "back" behaviour... That's the only way?

Comment: The security level is different when running locally.

Comment: You'll be better off if your "back" button actually goes navigates (forward) to the page you're trying to go back to.  This may not be possible in a (login/return to where you were which could be anywhere) scenario.  Older sites handled this by passing the current url in the url to the login page, eg: `/login?returnUrl=home`.

Comment: Alternatively, consider using ajax to post the form then you don't get form resubmission issue.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution (and a general best practice) is that a `POST` submission be followed by a redirect on success which takes user to a page which can be accessed through a direct URL.

Comment: I need to take the user back to the search screen, with the results being displayed.